# c# html agility pack skips over character

Tags: c#, html, .net, html-agility-pack

I am using htmlAgilityPack with c# to read the contents of a html file.
There are lines of text within this file that look like that:

```
<td>info info info info info info info info info ><info info info info <\td>
```

When I read the content of the "TD" mark, the text I get in return is :

```
info info info info info info info info info >
```

instead of

```
info info info info info info info info info ><info info info info
```

my guess is that the reader treats the '<' character as an "open tag" character

is any of you familiar with this?

Comment: html is malformed. `>` and `<` should be escaped as `&gt;` `&lt;`

Comment: @DanielHilgarth http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes#use

Comment: @I4V: I am unable to find what I was remembering. Going to remove my comments as I have no credible source to back them up.

Comment: the closing TD also looks strange...

Comment: that's because i actually wrote it instead of pasting it.
problem is that i cant change the html. i need to use it as is.

Comment: Can you add your code where you parse the td, just for a full picture of how you are doing it

Comment: agree with @Simon, the closing TD should be </td> not <\td>